# URL rewrite issue with WCF services

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I am at the tail end of a project that rewrites our existing public endpoints to be hosted in IIS (our current implementation was written before IIS7 and is a home-grown hosting application).

I'm also at my wits end with trying to get the URL Rewrite functionality to work properly so that we can seamlessly move our existing customers over to the new endpoints.  I'm having a couple of issues with running the new endpoints alongside our legacy app.

I thought this would work fine:

Legacy URL:
https://mydevserver:443/2.0.22/ServiceA

New URL:
https://mydevserver:9995/2.1.22/ServiceB.svc

Rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="Test">  
  <match url="2.0.22/ServiceA" />  
  <action type="Rewrite" url="2.1.22/ServiceB.svc" />  
</rule>
```

So I shut down the legacy service, fired up my client and pointed it to the legacy service URL, but I get an error that there is no endpoint listening.  Which makes sense to me, as that URL is registered by our legacy app and it's not available:

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://mydevserver:443/2.0.22/ServiceA that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
>   InnerException, if present, for more details.

So I thought if I changed the binding port in IIS for my new endpoints to be the https default, it would work -

New URL:
[same as legacy]/2.1.22/ServiceB.svc

This prompts IIS to give me a warning that the binding is already being used by a product other than IIS, and I might overwrite the existing cert for the address/port combination.  So I say OK, and rebind the cert to the 443 port (for good measure), but when I point my client to the old URL, I get sort of the same error but it's worded a little differently:

> The HTTP service located at https://mydevserver:443/2.0.22/ServiceA is
>   unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or because
>   no endpoint was found listening at the specified address. Please
>   ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the service again
>   later.

I feel like I've tried every combination of everything (wildcard matches, paths, etc.) but I am clearly missing something.  I would appreciate any help on this issue.

*Also, is it even possible to host the IIS endpoints on a different server and use URL rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

From further research, I have determined that this is not possible:

> You can only rewrite the URL in the same site and same application
>   pool.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/08/25/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite.aspx